# GLFW convert codepoints to characters in glfwCharCallback

Tags: c++, input, char, glfw

I cant figure out how to parse the codepoint in a char in my glfwCharCallback:

```
std::string currentText;

void char_callback(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int codepoint)
{
    // currentText += codepoint ???
}

...

glfwSetCharCallback(window, char_callback);
```

Comment: That depends on what you do with `currentText`. If you want to render it to a bitmap you're better off accumulating the UTF-32 code points directly. For all other use cases you should probably encode it to UTF-8 and stick it in a `std::string`

Comment: I would like it to use it as a standard std::string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, you can simply truncate the `unsigned int` to a `unsigned char` and appending it to your `std::string`:

```
currentText += (unsigned char) codepoint;
```

Note that this is criminally wrong for anything beyond basic ASCII. As I remarked in the comments, you probably want to either store UTF-32 codepoints for rendering using freetype, or convert to UTF-8 for printing to console or storage.